# How to add current activity to Activity Stack

Tags: android, android-activity

Can anyone tell me if there is any way to add current activity to Activity Stack (Activities history). I have situation as following:

1. user starts new activity - A (which I don't want to put on stack)
2. user starts new activity (B) from A
3. user presses BACK button from B
4. B is gone, but A is gone also

When user starts activity B, I want to keep A in history to be able to move back with BACK button.

The only thing I have in my mind is to starts new activity A from B in onKeyDown() method. But maybe is there a better way?

Comment: If you want to refresh you activity "A" when it is called from B then use onActivityResult to refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" in your root activity (in the manifest file)

also, unless you want to prevent going from B to A (when the user press back), you should drop the "no history" flag

docs:

If this attribute is set to "true" in the root activity of a task, the stack is cleared down to the root activity whenever the user leaves the task and returns to it. In other words, it's the polar opposite of alwaysRetainTaskState. The user always returns to the task in its initial state, even after a momentary absence

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#clearstack
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear

Comment: It would be great if that has worked. The problem is that it isn't. In other question someone told that HOME button doesn't finish root activity so it can't be re-launched..

Comment: Maybe I add that the activity A is started from my widget. Don't know if it changes anything

Comment: have set clear task on launch on Activity A *and* removed the no history flag? how did that go?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't call finish() for activity A when user starts activity B it will be there when user finishes activity B.

Comment: if I start activity A with flag Intent.Activity_flag_no_history, then it won't. That's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

That's actually what happens in the normal lifecycle of an application. If you don't call `finish()` in A, the application will return to A when B finishes.

Comment: Why exactly do you have to use this flag, if you want to go back to your app ? Please explain a little more why you had to put this flag, that would help us to answer you.

Comment: Because I want to prevent situation like: user starts activity A -> user starts activity B from A -> user presses HOME button -> user starts activity A, but it moves straight to B